# Subtract loan payment every month with daily compounding interest

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to subtract a monthly loan payment with daily compounded interest. Right now I think I've got the right code for subtracting the payment amount daily over a 10 year loan:

```
P = 20000
r  = .068 
t  = 10
n  = 365

payment = 200

for payment_number in xrange(1, n*t):

    daily_interest = P * (1+(r/n)) - P

    P = (P + daily_interest) - payment

    print P
```

I'd like it if possible to still print the daily balances but instead subtract the payment every month rather than every day. Initially I though maybe use a nested for loop with xrange(1, 30) but I'm not sure that worked correctly. Thanks in advance for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

What about inserting an if statement for the purpose?

```
P = P-200 if payment_number%30 == 0 else P
```

This will run if the `payment_number` variable is a multiple of 30.

Comment: dont forget february.

Answer (score 0):

"Monthly" is a complicated idea. To fully handle the months you will need to use the datetime module.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
date_started = date(2000,1,1)
```

So say you are 123 days from the start date, we need to calculate that date:

```
date = date_started + timedelta(days=123)
>>> date
datetime.date(2000, 5, 3)
```

So now we know need to figure how many days are between that date and the first of the month, the dateutil module can help us with that (you will have to download it).

```
from dateutil.relativedata import relativedelta
firstofmonth_date = date_started + relativedelta(months=4)
tddays = firstofmonth_date - date_started
days = tddays.days
```

Then just put "days" into the function you already have and you should be good. The only part I left for you to do is figuring out how many months have passed between your dates.